# Using a JMeter JDBC connection in Java code

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter

I'm working on a Java Request class for use in JMeter.  The class needs to have access to the same database that's being used by the rest of the test plan.  Is there a way to access the test plan's JDBC Connection from Java code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you have the following [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) configuration:

[image]

You can access connection this way using a [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) + Groovy+Cache Key (whatever unique String you want):

[image]

If you want to copy paste, Sampler contains this:

> ```
> import java.sql.Connection;
> import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement;
> Connection conn = DataSourceElement.getConnection("jdbcConfig");
> // Ensure you close conn
> ```

Comment: Thank you!  Looks like Java Request Samplers also have access to the DataSourceElement class.  So it should work in that environment, too.  I wish this was in the JMeter documentation.