# Manipulating JMeter JDBC connection fields in Java/beanshell code

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter, beanshell

This is a followup to [Using a JMeter JDBC connection in Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266923/using-a-jmeter-jdbc-connection-in-java-code).  How do I use the methods such as getPassword() or getUsername in the DataSourceElement class?  I want to get and then modify the username and password (among other things) from the JDBC Connection Configuration config.

I'm using the same code in that post, but in a beanshell sampler (which will ultimately be used in a preprocessor element).  I think the problem is that I need a DataSourceElement object and have only defined a Connection object.  That is where I am stuck.

My code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement;
print("\nbeanshell script beginning");

try {
        Connection con = DataSourceElement.getConnection("jdbcconfig");
        print(con);
        String conpasswd = con.getPassword();
        print(conpasswd);
        if(con!=null)
        con.close();
}

catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Something went wrong: ", ex);
}

print("the end");
```

jmeter.log returns this:

```
ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.sql.Connection; import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSo . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method getPassword() not found in class'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0'
```

And the console output returns the connection object and then stops at the error:

```
beanshell script beginning
org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@7849e2a7
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get some connection information using [DatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) class like:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;

Connection con = DataSourceElement.getConnection("jdbcconfig");
DatabaseMetaData meta = con.getMetaData();
String conusername = meta.getUserName();
print(conusername);
```

But I **don't** think you will be able to get the password this way as the ability would cause immense security risks.

By the way, you can get more friendly exception message in *jmeter.log* file by surrounding your Beanshell code into try/catch block like:

```
try {
    //your code here
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Something wrong", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more information on using JMeter and Java APIs from Beanshell test elements