# Dynamically change JDBC config in Jmeter

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter, beanshell

I need to make sure,whether table  has data or not ,based on the environment,say for example i have  two two database,one is  development another one is production like given below.

```
Production 
host1
dbuser1
dbpassword1
dburl
Tablename : studentinfo

Development
dbuser2
dbpassword2
dburl2
Tablename : studentinfo
```

FYI : studentinfo has same structure in both environment .

In Jmeter ,User Defined Variable( UDV), I have configured two set of database information. Using BeanShell Processor I have trying to change the database connectivity information, Is there any way to change the Db Config dynamically ?

Given below is my Jmeter UDV

```
env : prod
prod_db_url: dburl
prod_db_user:usr
prod_db_password:password

dev_db_url: dburl
dev_db_user:usr
dev_db_password:password
```

In My Beanshell Preprocessor

```
String env=vars.get("env");
if(env.equlas("prod")){
   // Load the Prod db into vars
} else if (env.equals("dev")){
   // Load the Dev db into vars
}
```

Here ,I am setting the values in vars, and trying to get the information from DB Configuration variables. but i am not able get values the in DB config.

Can anyone explain ? what went wrong or what is the approach to get connection?

Comment: Similar question ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779835/manipulating-jmeter-jdbc-connection-fields-in-java-beanshell-code?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need a Beanshell PreProcessor for this.

For the below UDV,

```
env : prod
prod_db_url: dburl
prod_db_user:usr
prod_db_password:password

dev_db_url: dburl
dev_db_user:usr
dev_db_password:password
```

Just by changing the value of env, you can access all the variables values by using

`${__V(${env}_db_url)}`  // return prod or dev db url depends on the value of env.

---

**Another nice solution:**

Can you have the same variables and store them in 2 different property files?

**prod.proeprties**

```
db_url=dburl
db_user=usr
db_password=password
```

**dev.properties**

```
db_url=dburl
db_user=usr
db_password=password
```

You can use the JMeter - [Property File Reader.](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/)

Property reader file path would be `/path/to/${env}.properties`
Access all the variables using `${__P(db_url)}`, `${__P(db_user)}`

Comment: I am not able to load the .properties file using ${env}.properties, i am getting null.

Comment: @VasanthDha, env should be a UDV. It can not be in the property file itself

Answer (score 5):

JDBC Connection Configuration is initialized after User Defined Variables but  **before** any PreProcessor, that's why you don't see values changes.

Consider using JMeter Properties instead of JMeter Variables, i.e. change `${dburl}` in JDBC Connection Configuration to `${__P(dburl,)}`. Do the same for credentials variables.

Depending on how you run your test you can set properties value:

1. Via `-J` command-line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -Jdburl=jdbc://somedb:port/etc -Juser=foo -Jpassword=bar
   ```
2. Put it into *user.properties* file (located in JMeter's "bin" folder) like

   ```
   dburl=jdbc://somedb:port/etc
   user=foo
   password=bar
   ```

References:

- [__P() function user manual entry](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: this is something that is hidden in the jmeter documentation 
can you point me where in the hell in the JMeter doc JDBC Configuration initialized  before any PreProcessor??
Thanks!!!